# This in Private context

Tags: javascript, variables, object, scope, private

I would like to access variables created inside a private context. I'm creating a private context like this:

```
(new Function("var a = 'hello'; console.log('this', this);")).call({});
// outputs -> this Object {}
```

I'm `call`'ing the function with an empty context. But `this` doesn't holds the `a` variable. And anyway how is it possible that `console.log` works with an empty context?

Comment: Why not just call console.log('this', a); ?

Comment: because I would like to access all the variables that were created inside the context.

Answer (score 2):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/26e5v/)**

Inside of the scope for the function which creates the object `var a` is present. However, once that scope is lost, so is the variable. If you would like `a` to persist, you would need to attach it to the object that is created using the `this` keyword:

```
(new Function("this.a = 'hello'; console.log(this);")).call({});
```

However, this is an obfuscated way of doing it. There are elements which are not required here. Mainly that the `new` keyword is not needed ([`Function`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0140__Function/FunctioncapitalF.htm) implies a function object). `Function` also comes with methods, such as `call`.

```
Function("this.a = 'hello'; console.log(this);").call({});
```

This will also work. Moreover, if you would like to retain what is in the variable a, you could always do this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8sU65/1)):

```
var obj = {};
Function("this.a = 'hello'").call(obj);
obj.a;//hello
```

---

As for why it works with an empty context. You have actually given it a freshly constructed object with `{}`. So that is the scope that is used inside of the function when the reference `this` is encountered. In fact, `call()` does not need arguments if you are not intending to use scope. Something like this:

```
Function("console.log(5);").call();
```

will log `5` to the console without error.

---

The approach used in your question is to build a function from a magic string. That approach is pretty cool I must say, very similar to eval. But what you are looking for boils down to this difference I think:

```
function ball(){
 var color = "red";
 return color;
}

function Ball(){
 this.color = "red";
}

console.log(ball());//logs red
console.log(new Ball().color);//logs red
```

Comment: Just a tiny detail. Since you don't store a reference to the empty object, you will never be able to access the `a` variable outside this way either.

Comment: @HoLyVieR - It shows on the log as present on the object. It is true that the only scope of this object is in this one liner so there will be no future access available and the whole mess will be eligible for garbage collection after execution.

Comment: How is that even if I append the parent context I still can't get the `a`? `(new Function("var a = 'hello'; console.log(this.a);")).call(this);` returns undefined

Comment: @Adam - There is a difference between `this.a` and `var a`. If you were to use `console.log(a)` there is would log `hello`.

Comment: Yes, but the whole reason for me to do this, is to have an object which holds the variables that I create inside the context.